# Eclipse Java; export jar, include referenced libraries, without fatjar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I need to export jar from my Eclipse Java project and I want to include the referenced libraries. I can't use fatjar for this, which is what everyone seems to recommend. There must be another way of doing this. Does anyone know what this is?!

Comment: Please explain why you can't use farjar. Everyone recommends it because that's what everyone uses and it works well. So why should there be a another tool to do the same thing?? *confused*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The next version of Eclipse (3.5, due next June) has an option to include all necessary jars. It was introduced in 3.5M5 (thanks, [basszero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287/basszero)).

Or you can try to build your project with [Maven 2](http://maven.apache.org/). Then, you can build a "fat" jar with [`mvn assembly:assembly`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/index.html).

Another option is to use [ant](http://ant.apache.org/). Unpack all JAR files into a temp directory and jar them up again.

Comment: The recent milestone version of Eclipse (3.5M5) includes the feature you just mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

I think its version 3.3 of Eclipse (ganymede) that has Export as **Runnable JAR file**. Last time I tried it, it did include the referenced libraries and also un-jars all the jars.

Answer (score 3):

This feature of eclipse works just fine to dump only the referenced libraries into separate folder. "Export as Runnable Jar" with "Copy the referenced libraries into a subfolder .." option.

Comment: This is almost the same answer as that provided by @bernie-perez. Should have been posted as a comment to that answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just posting a little (Helios) gotcha for using the Eclipse export Jar - you must first run (in Eclipse) a class with a main() method, otherwise the "Launch configuration" dropdown will be blank and you'll not be able to export.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could modify your build script to include the libraries. If I undestand correctly you can put into your 
`<jar destfile="myProject.jar"> ... <zipfileset src="theExternalLib.jar"> </jar>`

Answer (score 0):

You can export an XML file from eclipse,then analyse the file to get the jars you want - see [this](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-share-an-eclipse-user-library-with-other-users.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

I used a maven project instead of a java project and it worked !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32970092)