# Eclipse Order and Export

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, I have a project TEST which is dependent on Project TEST2 and an externat jar external.jar. While creating jar for TEST Project with Order and Export option checked , created jar is not including TEST2.jar or external.jar.. So how I can do this to run the TEST.jar idependently ?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528007/eclipse-java-export-jar-include-referenced-libraries-without-fatjar) is a related SO question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options are possible here. First:

Add TEST2 in Java Build Path > Projects of TEST1 project.

Second:

1. Convert your TEST and TEST2 project into a Facet project: Properties > Project Facets.
2. Click on Utility Module in list of facets in TEST2
3. Add Project TEST2 in Deployment Assembly of TEST project