# How to add JDBC driver to the project?

Tags: jdbc, project, driver

I am a begginer in Java, and I managed to create an app that stores (and also displays into a JTable) data into a database located on my computer. I made an executable .jar out of it and it works like a charm (on my PC). My problem comes when I am running that app on another PC.

```
try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't find driver");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

I always get that message dialog "Can't find driver". I am asking for an answer regarding how to add (somehow) the driver that I need into my executable .jar file in order to run properly on other PCs.

Comment: have you got `OracleDriver` in your classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Class.forName()` will try to load the class based on its name from the classpath, dynamically(*), so you need to make sure you have the proper class (`OracleDriver`) on your classpath.  Keep in mind it will usually be contained in a .jar, so you need to put that on the classpath.

(*) In this case the driver registers itself when the class is loaded

The easiest way to ensure you *have* that jar is to distribute it with your project (see licencing for the particular driver whether that is an option in your case)

Comment: I put the jar file (ojdbc6.jar) containing that class on my classpath (Add External JARs) and it still doesn't work. I am starting to think that I am missing something in the Export process.

Comment: You could look into the fatjar plugin (hanven't used it myself), or follow the suggestions in [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528007/eclipse-java-export-jar-include-referenced-libraries-without-fatjar)

Comment: Problem solved! I used Runnable JAR file from the Export menu. Thanks for answering my question Attila !