# Export android library project as jar

Tags: android, jar, project, noclassdeffounderror

I want to export android library project including couple of jar files inside "libs" folder as a jar file and put it in other android application project.

The problem is, when I include generated jar file in other android application project, it doesn't see jar files from android library project and throws `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: Why dont you just add the other jars to the new project?
Possible same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422892/how-to-export-a-jar-file-including-my-classes-and-other-jar-files-extracted-us

Answer (score -1):

I see one of the following reasons :

- There could be few other classes which your jars(in libs) are referencing.
- When you add your project jar to another project, the classes are being loaded by separate classloaders.

The stacktrace would make it clear. You can follow this to [debug the NoClassDefFoundError](http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html)