# How to add jar library into jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I created a library which uses the bluecove library. It works well but when I export the library into jar, and include into the other project, it looks that it can't found the bluecove class files.

```
Exception in thread "main" 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/bluetooth/LocalDevice
```

I think there is a problem about exporting the jar with the dependencies. How can I export my java library as jar including the bluecove as well in Eclipse?

---

*please explain why downvoted this question? It would be great to give some reason, letting me improve my question.*

Comment: Don't do that.  It will ruin digital signatures & quite possibly the manifest of the 3rd party API.  Simply ensure the dependent Jar is on the run-time class-path.

Comment: Do as Andrew advices, or if you really want to include the library,  see [Eclipse Java; export jar, include referenced libraries, without fatjar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528007/eclipse-java-export-jar-include-referenced-libraries-without-fatjar) or use the [Fat Jar plugin](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: You should use separeted jars and include them in your classpath.

Comment: Take a look at the fat-jar plugin for eclipse. It can help you to achieve what you are looking for [Link](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thank you, but why is it a bad question? Sorry for duplicate I didnt found that with google.

Comment: Here is how to do that with Eclipse:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033603/how-to-create-a-jar-with-external-libraries-included-in-eclipse

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have one big jar that contains your code and all your dependencies, you could use tools such as Jar Jar Links (https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/). This tool allows you to repackage multiple JARs in a single JAR.

But I would simply quote Andrew Thompson:
*"Don't do that. It will ruin digital signatures & quite possibly the manifest of the 3rd party API. Simply ensure the dependent Jar is on the run-time class-path"*

Answer (score 0):

If you use a build file like ant you can use the jar task to add all your jars dependencies into one which we have successfully done on a number of projects but as Algiz pointed out you will run into problems with some jars which require their manifest files.

There are ways around this.